# How to send same Object to Different Parse Class

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have created two ParseObjects which I want to saveInBackGround at the sametime.

```
protected ParseObject aroundPost(){
    ParseObject around = new ParseObject(ParseConstants.CLASS_AROUNDME);
    around.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME,ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    around.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_ID, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());

    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("peeps", fileBytes);
    ParseFile thumbs = new ParseFile("thumbs",image);
    around.put(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE, file);
    around.put(ParseConstants.KEY_THUMB, thumbs);

    if (fileBytes == null) {
        return null;
    } else {

        return around;
    }
}

protected ParseObject createMessage() {
    ParseObject message = new ParseObject(ParseConstants.CLASS_MESSAGES);
    message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_ID, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_RECIPIENT_IDS, getRecipientIds());


    if (fileBytes == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        ParseFile file = new ParseFile("peeps", fileBytes);
        ParseFile thumbs = new ParseFile("thumbs",image);
        message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE, file);
        message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_THUMB, thumbs);

        return message;
    }
}
```

I have created Send function to upload the data to ParseCloud.

```
protected void send(ParseObject message) {

            message.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        // success!
                        Toast.makeText(RecipientsActivity.this, R.string.success_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecipientsActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage(R.string.error_sending_message)
                                .setTitle(R.string.error_selecting_file_title)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                }
```

This is my OnClickListener which runs the function of send. Here I have added Object createMessage But How can I add aroundPost to upload at the same time?

```
@Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Click action
                    ParseObject message = createMessage();
                    if (message == null) {
                        // error
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecipientsActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage(R.string.error_selecting_file)
                                .setTitle(R.string.error_selecting_file_title)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    } else {
                        send(message);
                        finish();
                    }
```

Comment: you cannot store two objects in different Class with just one request in parse... If I were you I would just upload one Object and do the other one with cloud code, otherwise it is poor desing, Network request are very expensive!

Comment: @MazelTov I am new with Parse could you tell how do I go about with the 2nd Object to another class with cloud code?

Comment: check this tutorial first :-) https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-aftersave-triggers